# Simple AllJoyn Test with Android Studio - no communication

Tags: android-studio, alljoyn

I'm trying to get a very simple/basic AllJoyn test app working with Android Studio (v1.5.1).
It compiles and starts successfully at a real Android device.

AllJoyn.jar and liballjoyn_java.so from v15.09a are included, the .so lib is found:

```
D/dalvikvm: Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.test.alljoyntest-2/liballjoyn_java.so 0x417d1010 
D/dalvikvm: Added shared lib /data/app-lib/com.test.alljoyntest-2/liballjoyn_java.so 0x417d1010
```

Unfortunately I get no bus events, announcements etc., my breakpoints are never hit. Other AllJoyn apps and devices find eachother on my WiFi net, so there is traffic which could and should be seen.

Android permissions are set as recommended:
ACCESS_WIFI_STATE, CHANGE_WIFI_STATE, CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE, INTERNET

Although having set those permissions, logcat shows one suspect line:

```
E/PERMISSION_MGR:    0.995 ****** ERROR PERMISSION_MGR lepDisp2_0 ...ndroid/PermissionDB.cc:182 |  0x0001
```

Might this be a hint for more permissions being necessary? Which?

Maybe there is a simple and *working* AllJoyn example for Android Studio on the net which I could try and track the communication problem of my project down?
Hard to believe, but I didn't find one so far...

Comment: did you manage to have this working? I'm having the same issue. Thank you.

Comment: @HeliG if anyone have solve this error can you please help me

Comment: @HeliG : I am facing same issue have you got the answer?